# Dirac delta function integral only at a specific point

Tags: limits, dirac-delta

From what I understand the Dirac delta function is infinitely thin at every point except for one, where its infinite. 
I was wondering if we completely disregard the function at every point except for where its infinite,
then is it possible to rewrite it as :
$$\int_{- \infty}^{+\infty} \delta (x) = 
\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{- \epsilon}^{+\epsilon} \delta (x) = 1
$$
or in a more general case : 
$$
\int_{- \infty}^{+\infty} \delta (x - a) \psi (x) = 
\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{- \epsilon}^{+\epsilon} \delta (x-a) \psi(x) = \psi(a)
$$
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Both limits should be limits from the right. Also, for the more general case, your second equation should be
$$
\int_{- \infty}^{+\infty} \delta (x - a) \psi (x) = 
\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{a - \epsilon}^{a+\epsilon} \delta (x-a) \psi(x)
$$

Comment: It is indeed correct to say that 
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \int_{- \epsilon}^{+\epsilon} \delta (x)\,dx= 1,
$$
But the expression $\int_0^0 \delta(x)\,dx$ is still problematic, if that's the kind of thing that you were getting at.